# Open problems in nuclear fusion

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

I'm starting to learn about the nuclear fusion and wonder what are (if any) the major open theoretical/computational problems in this field? Ideally something related to the properties of quantum mamy-body systems, such as scattering of complex bound states against each other. Which quantities of interest can we predict poorly at this point, due to the inadequacy of existing models and/or lack of computational resources?

Comment: The most significant issues on the theoretical side have to do with the mass behaviour of plasma at the extreme conditions of modern reactors. In particular, the issue of "edge localized modes", where the plasma suddenly jets out of the reaction area and can damage the reactor wall. On the laser side of things, we still can't accurately predict implosion dynamics, after 50 years of trying and about nine orders of magnitude more computing power applied.